# Meaning of COBOL syntax: hash and dot at line beginning

Tags: cobol

I'm currently reading a COBOL program and I'm wondering about the meaning of two syntactical details:

- dot at *the beginning of a line*
- hash at variable/identifier

I'm aware of the meaning of a dot at the *end of a line* as a ending marker for a logical block, but I can't find anything on the start of a line. Might not be relevant at all, but I'm afraid that it could be some label or preprocessor instruction.

According to my findings the 7th symbol on a line is the so called 'indicator'and the only valid characters are * / and -

Also has the hash in an identifier any special meaning ?

Example 1:

```
      /****************************************************************
      *multi line comment blabla...
      *****************************************************************
       X008-DO-SOMETHING SECTION.

      .IF  #28,<>,,
           INITIALIZE #25-DATA-AREA
      .END
```

Example 2:

```
026100     SET W-DATEN-READM TO TRUE
026110     .ADD XBVMACP,#XX13-OCU-MAP-I0156 (1)
026120
026130
026140.***************************************************************
026150.* blabla                                                      *
026230.***************************************************************
026240.SL BLGMA
```

Thanks for feedback, besides from that COBOL is of course awesome ;-)

Comment: The 7th column is a continuation column, mostly used to continue long strings.  Other common symbols in the 7th column are an asterisk for comments and with some compilers, a slash allows the programmer to modify the compiler defaults or otherwise give instructions to the compiler.  On some compilers, a slash in the 7th column causes the printed output to skip to the top of the next page.  I'm not sure what a pound sign leading variable signifies.

Comment: `.` and `#` are not cobol. I would guess some sort of pre-compiler/macro language. The `.` indicates a *macro* command follows. The `#` indicates a cobol variable follows. What Cobol/environment are we dealing with ??

Comment: @BruceMartin Apparently you are right, it seems to be a macro. In this case the code between two .SL statements seems to be copied into another template and only then compiled to COBOL. Do you have by any chance a hint for documentation on how macros work in general?

Comment: I do not remember seeing this syntax before. I just figured it out what was going on (experience ?). I have know idea of what it actually is; That is why I asked what environment it comes from